# modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

In `EntityFramework 6.x`, if we have lots of `EntityConfiguration` classes then we can assign all of them in `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` as follows instead of one by one:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly);
}
```

**Is there anything like** `modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly` **in** **Entity Framework Core.**

Comment: I don't think there is. You can open an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/

Comment: Thank you. Okay I shall.

Comment: @TanvirArjel If you open an issue, post the link back here somewhere if you would. I'm curious to hear the answer to this one.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett Here is the submitted issue link : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13026

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### For EF Core <= 2.1

You can write an extension method as follows:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyAllConfigurations(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
            .Any(gi => gi.IsGenericType && gi.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>))).ToList();

        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(configurationInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurations();
}
```

### For EF Core >= 2.2

From EF Core 2.2 you don't need to write any custom extension method. EF Core 2.2 added `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` extension method for this purpose. You can just use it as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfiguration).Assembly); // Here UseConfiguration is any IEntityTypeConfiguration
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfiguration).Assembly);` seems a little awkward, having to use an arbitrary class in the assembly to figure out which assembly to use (in this case using the `UserConfiguration` class).  Is there any reason to prefer that way of doing things to .`modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(this.GetType().Assembly);`, assuming the configuration classes and the derived DbContext class are in the same assembly?  Is `typeof(<configuration class>)` faster than `this.GetType()`?

Comment: For EF Core 3.1 released on 2019 December, the command line must be `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`

Comment: Thanks! Your post was very helpful - we needed to downgrade 2.2 to 2.1 (as 2.2 is out of support) and used your method :)