# Entity Framework Core modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly scan all Configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Refer: [modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842709/modelbuilder-configurations-addfromassembly-in-ef-core)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfiguration).Assembly); // Here UseConfiguration is any IEntityTypeConfiguration
}
```

I've taken the above from the StackOverflow URL above.

In my OnModelCreating, I have multiple ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly, one line for each Configuration.

```
1. modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(CustomerConfiguration).Assembly); 
2. modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(OrderConfiguration).Assembly); 
3. modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ProductConfiguration).Assembly);
```

When I was doing a debug, what I notice is that when executing line 1, the program does not only execute CustomerConfiguration.  It also execute the other Configuration.  This is the same when executing line 2 and line 3.

I also notice that there are some Configuration which were in the same folder but was not mentioned in OnModelCreating, they were also executed.

1. Is this the correct way to code the program if I have a number of Configurations ?
2. If yes, how does EF know about the other Configuration and scan it ?
3. Should I just have 1 ApplyConfiguration ?  If yes, how do I decided which one to mention ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `CustomerConfiguration` and `OrderConfiguration` are placed in different libraries (assemblies)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The are in the same Assembly.  In my debug, I check the value of typeof(CustomerConfiguration).Assembly and typeof(OrderConfiguration).Assembly.  Both point to the same dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ModelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.applyconfigurationsfromassembly?view=efcore-7.0) as clear from the name will apply all configurations from the passed assembly:

> Applies configuration from all `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` instances that are defined in provided assembly.

So it seems that `CustomerConfiguration`, `OrderConfiguration` and `ProductConfiguration` are in the same assembly (project).

> If yes, how does EF know about the other Configuration and scan it ?

You are passing an assembly, EF will use reflection to process it and find all classes implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>`.

> Should I just have 1 ApplyConfiguration ? If yes, how do I decided which one to mention ?

Yes. One per assembly containing your entity configurations (usually they are store in one). You can use any type from this assembly, not just the configuration ones.

Read more:

- [Assemblies in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/)
- [Reflection (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)
- [`ModelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/767bc93c6e6fca19868f486c7df8f4235bcf53cd/src/EFCore/ModelBuilder.cs#L507)

Comment: Thanks for your answer !   So, as long as I can supply the Assembly, it will scan all the IEntityTypeConfiguration found there.  Is using "typeof(CustomerConfiguration).Assembly" the only way to supply the Assembly ?  I ask because I find it a bit awkward.  It's like saying the assembly belong to CustomerConfiguration.  Thanks.

Comment: @EBDS yes, there are but this is by far the shortest and easiest AFAIK. Don't read it as assembly belonging to type, read it as type knowing which assembly it belongs too.

Comment: Thanks again.  I think that's where I got confused from the beginning.  Thanks for helping me clear it up.